# Div text doesn't change to API property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing the FCC front end certification and I can't handle right the api:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/", function(data) {
    var city = data.city;
    lat = data.lat;
    long = data.lon;
    $("#long").text("The weather for  " + city + " is:");
    url = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/b537d8225ba7eaa6a34d16afbae307c3/" + lat + "," + long;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      temp = data.currently;
      $("#tmp").text("b");
    });
    $("#tmp").text(temp);
  });
  $("#tmp").text(temp);
});
```

However,tmp does not change it's text to var temp,
even that by The Dark Sky Forecast I can see my callback had received,
thank you!

Comment: That url doesn't send a CORS header that allows cross domain requests, so your `success` callback won't be reached. You should see a message on the console about it. It does seem to allow for a JSONP response though

Comment: Thank you! But I tried and it didn't work, can you help me handle the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the cors as @PatrickEvans mentioned. Try this hombre:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data)
        var city = data.city;
        lat = data.lat;
        long = data.lon;
        $("#long").text("The weather for  " + city + " is:");
        url = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/b537d8225ba7eaa6a34d16afbae307c3/?" + lat + "," + long + "&callback=?";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            var temp = data.currently;
            $("#tmp").text("b");
        });
        $("#tmp").text(temp);
    });
    $("#tmp").text(temp);
});
```

also, read up on jsonp

Comment: Thanks! But it still won't run on codePen,do you have any idea why? Ive been stuck on this for about 5 hours

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqgxjJ?editors=1111 The ap-api works, the forecast doesnt. How did you get the link? Do you have to use that weather api?

Comment: No I didn't, but the api that FCC suggested was not working, so I looked for another one, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

-Fixed the `CORS` issue as @Martin Gottweis suggested you. (The ip-api doesn't need callback, but the forecast one yes)

-Inside your forecast getJSON function, you retrieve `.currently`, but it's only an object with more data inside, you have to specify what you want (for example `.summary`).

-Moved the code from outside the forecast getJSON so it can access `temp` variable.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/", function(data) {
            var city = data.city;
            lat = data.lat;
            long = data.lon;
            $("#long").text("The weather for  " + city + " is:");
            url = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/b537d8225ba7eaa6a34d16afbae307c3/" + lat + "," + long + "?callback=?";
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                temp = data.currently.summary;
                $("#tmp").text(temp);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Ive been stuck for a day!